# Prefix in XML schema root

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>...
```

Hello. I have following question about the code above. Why does the root element have a "xs:" prefix, altough it's defined not until the xmlns reference? Is that a mistake (it's an example code from wiki)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces can be defined on any element node (including the document element). They will be used for this element all it's child and attribute nodes until redefined on another element node.

Here is no reason that a parser can not look at the xmlns attributes of an element node to resolve it's prefix.

An how would you define the namespace for the document element otherwise? It is the first element node.